# How to show separate values in Views from multi-value field

Tags: views

I made Multi-valued field in content type. I created image type of field and let it has unlimited number of images.
Is it possible in Views to show only first image from this field? And only 5th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust these settings in your view for the image field:

[image]